# Is there a way to remove my custom info path form , and re-create my default Edit/Create view for my issue tracking App

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, page-layout, custom-form

I have edited the Create view for my issue tracking list using the IE info path custom form, the result was not what I am planning to have. And I need to retrieve or re-create the default Create view and remove my info path form . so is there a way to do so ?
Thnaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. In the list go to List Settings > Form Settings and tick "Use the default SharePoint Form". If you keep the option "Delete the InfoPath form from the server" unticked, you can later switch back to the IP form. If you tick that option, it will be gone for good.